# How to Detect XAMPP is Running on Win 10

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I have a medical laboratory client with their Lab Information System (LIS) running on Win 10.

When they create the patient result reports they are faxed to some of their clients.
Faxing is done using an online fax service (faxage.com).
This fax process is initiated daily by calling a PHP script running on Win 10 with XAMPP 7.3.2
at https://127.0.0.1/

Sometimes XAMPP is not running Apache when they attempt to fax
The client then asked me to pop up a reminder everyday when the fax button is pressed to remind them to check if Apache is running before initiating the fax PHP script.
I am not a fan of popups.  I'd rather start it if Apache is not running.
I could just start it whether it is running or not but I do not want to create a problem either.

**The Question.**
Is there a fast way for a Win app to detect if Apache is running or not running?
Where fast means a few milliseconds.
It must be done with no human intervention
I wrote both the LIS and the fax PHP script so I have full control over both.
Running an app, creating files, redirecting output to a file, and reading the file are viable options.

---

---

[image: LIS Faxing]

Comment: Try to connect to the port it's listening on, with a very short timeout?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to handle the symptom instead of curing the cause. But that rarely is a good idea. You should simply take care that the apache http server is running all of the time. No fancy logic required then. The apache http server is rock solid, there is absolutely no reason why it should _not_ be operated in the usual server manner, that is always on.